# Firefox ESR storing passwords during session?

Tags: passwords, web-browser, firefox

Can anyone else reproduce this while having Firefox NEVER remember passwords:

- open Firefox ESR
- log into Facebook
- x out of the Facebook tab
- open a new tab
- click on the Facebook thumbnail
- does it log you in automatically? (cause it does me!!!)

I have my Firefox security settings to NEVER remember passwords for sites, and for Facebook I always just close the option to click on my face to log in.

In my previous OS (Ubuntu 16.4.3) this behaviour wasn't happening (same browser) And if I close the whole Firefox program and open it again, it won't log in automatically.

I'm a security n00b so maybe someone just needs to explain what's happening behind the scenes here?

Answer (score 5):

> I have my Firefox security settings to NEVER remember passwords for sites

This just means that Firefox doesn't save the password itself.

Once you're logged in, Firefox stores a session cookie to remember you as a Facebook user without needing you to re-enter the password. This cookie doesn't automatically expire once you close the tab. So although your password value won't be remembered, your session will be.

- If you want Firefox to forget about your Facebook session once you close the window, you can use a [private browsing](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/private-browsing-use-firefox-without-history) window. (`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `P`)
- If you want Firefox to forget about your Facebook session once you quit the browser, you can change that in the settings. Go to *Preferences* > *Privacy & Security* > *History*. Choose *Use custom setting for history* and at *Accept cookies from websites* set *Keep until I close Firefox*:

  [image]

  [(Image source)](http://trendblog.net/delete-cookies-chrome-firefox/)

Comment: There are also add-ons that will let you choose whether you want to keep cookies or not on a per-domain basis.